# can I Reuse Reactjs components for ReApp

Tags: reactjs-flux

I am leaning towards using Reactjs for our Web UI.  Are there any resources/examples explaining how I can reuse or replace my Web based components emitting HTML with components supported by Reapp so that I can make a mobile app easily leveraging the same Actions and Stores?

Answer (score 0):

2 places spring to mind:

1. https://reapp.io/ui.html
2. https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-simple-shopping-cart-with-react-js-and-flux

Hope that helps